Python TypeError ('<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int')
import random
elements = {
    "normal": {"strong_against": ["None"], "weak_against": ["None"]},
    "fire": {"strong_against": ["earth", "ice"], "weak_against": ["water", "ice"]},
    "water": {"strong_against": ["fire", "poison"], "weak_against": ["earth", "electric"]},
    "earth": {"strong_against": ["water", "poison"], "weak_against": ["fire", "nature"]},
    "holy": {"strong_against": ["dark"], "weak_against": ["dark"]},
    "dark": {"strong_against": ["holy"], "weak_against": ["holy"]},
    "ice": {"strong_against": ["fire"], "weak_against": ["fire"]},
    "electric": {"strong_against": ["water"], "weak_against": ["earth"]},
    "poison": {"strong_against": ["nature"], "weak_against": ["earth", "water"]},
    "nature": {"strong_against": ["earth"], "weak_against": ["poison", "fire"]}
}
class armor:
    def __init__(self, name, defence, element=None):
        self.name = name
        self.defence = defence
        self.element = element
class weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, damage, element=None):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.element = element
class restore_spell:
    def __init__(self, name, restore_power,cost):
        self.name = name
        self.restore_power = restore_power
        self.cost = cost
class attack_spell:
    def __init__(self, name, attack_spell_power, cost, element=None):
        self.name = name
        self.attack_spell_power = attack_spell_power
        self.cost = cost
        self.element = element
class  status_effects:
    pass
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,armor=None,weapon=None,attack_spell=None,restore_spell=None,debuff=None,buff=None,max_health = 100,health=None,max_mp=48,mp=None,strength=18,defe=12,dex=10,magic=20,magic_defe=12,luck=16,evasion=2,exp=0,lvl=1,skill_points=0,attack_accuracy=100,max_lvl=100, base_d=0, base_d_m=0):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = max_health
        self.health = health if health is not None else max_health
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.attack_spell = attack_spell
        self.restore_spell = restore_spell
        self.buff = buff
        self.debuff = debuff
        self.max_mp = max_mp
        self.mp = mp if mp is not None else max_mp
        self.strength = strength
        self.defe = defe
        self.armor = armor
        self.dex = dex
        self.magic = magic
        self.magic_defe = magic_defe
        self.luck = luck
        self.evasion = evasion
        self.exp = exp
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.skill_points = skill_points
        self.attack_accuracy = attack_accuracy
        self.evasion = evasion
        self.max_lvl = max_lvl
        self.base_d_m = base_d_m
    def see_stats(self):
        print("max health: ", self.max_health,"/ health: ", self.health)
        print("max mp: ", self.max_mp,"/ mp: ", self.mp)
        print("strength: ", self.strength)
        print("defense: ", self.defe)
        print("magic defense: ", self.magic_defe)
        print("dexterity: ", self.dex )
        print("luck: ", self.luck)
        print("exp: ", self.exp)
        print("lvl: ", self.lvl)
    def see_gear(self):
        print("weapon: ", self.weapon.name if self.weapon else "None")
        print("armor: ", self.armor.name if self.armor else "None")
    def restore_health(self):
            if self.health < self.max_health and self.restore_spell and self.mp >= self.restore_spell.cost:
                self.health = min(self.health + self.restore_spell.restore_power, self.max_health)
                self.mp -= self.restore_spell.cost
                print(f"{self.name} used {self.restore_spell.name} and restored health to {self.health}")
            else:
                print(f"{self.name} cannot use the restore spell.")
    def calculate_base_d(self):
            return (self.strength + (self.weapon.damage if self.weapon else 0)) * random.uniform(0.9375, 1.0625)
    def calculate_base_d_m(self):
            return (self.magic + (self.attack_spell.attack_spell_power if self.attack_spell else 0)) * random.uniform(0.9375, 1.0625)
    def attack(self):
        attack_type = input("What kind of attack do you want to do (magic/physical): ").lower()
        if attack_type == "magic" or "m":
            if self.attack_spell and self.mp >= self.attack_spell.cost:
                self.mp -= self.attack_spell.cost
                return self.calculate_base_d_m()
            else:
                print("Not enough MP to cast a spell or no spell equipped.")
                return 0
        elif attack_type == "physical" or "p":
            return self.calculate_base_d()
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid attack type.")
            return 0

    def exp_to_next_lvl(self):
            if 1 <= self.lvl <= 9:
                return self.lvl * 100
            elif 10 <= self.lvl <= 15:
                return self.lvl  * 200
            else:
                return self.lvl * 300
    def  gain_exp(self, exp):
            self.exp += exp
            while self.exp >= self.exp_to_next_lvl():
                self.level_up()
    def level_up(self):
            self.exp -= self.exp_to_next_lvl
            self.lvl += 1
            self.skill_points += 5
            if 0 <= self.lvl <= 10:
                self.max_health += 75
                self.mp += 10
            elif 11 <= self.lvl <= 50:
                self.max_health += 150
                self.mp += 15
            elif 51 <= self.lvl <= 99:
                self.max_health +=250
                self.mp += 25
            else:
                print("you are at max lvl")

            print(f"Congratulations! You've reached level {self.lvl}")
    def s_skill_p(self):
            if self.skill_points >0:
                x = input("which skill you want to incrase:\nstrength\ndefense\nmagic\nmagic_defense\ndexterity\nluck ").lower()
                if x == 'strength':
                    self.strength += 1
                    self.skill_points -= 1
                elif x == 'defense':
                    self.defe += 1
                    self.skill_points -= 1
                elif x == 'magic':
                    self.magic += 1
                    self.skill_points -= 1
                elif x == 'magic_defense':
                    self.magic_defe += 1
                    self.skill_points -= 1
                elif x == 'dexterity':
                    self.dex += 1
                    self.skill_points -= 1
                elif x == 'luck':
                    self.luck += 1
                    self.skill_points -= 1
                else:
                    print("Please enter a valid skill")
            else:
                print("you dont have skill points ")
    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0

class  Barbarian(Person):
    pass
class Wizard(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, max_health=None, health=None, max_mp=48, mp=None, magic=20, magic_defe=12, attack_spells=None):
        super().__init__(name, max_health, health, max_mp, mp, magic=magic, magic_defe=magic_defe)
        self.attack_spells = attack_spells if attack_spells is not None else []

class Monster(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, max_health=100, health=None, max_mp=48, mp=None, magic=20, magic_defe=12, element=None, attack_spells=None):
        super().__init__(name, max_health, health, max_mp, mp, magic, magic_defe, element, attack_spells)
        self.element = element
        self.attack_spells = attack_spells if attack_spells is not None else []

    def attack_m(self):
        if self.health > self.max_health * 0.5:
            return self.calculate_base_d()
        else:
            return self.calculate_base_d_m()
def battle(player, monster):
    while not player.is_dead() and not monster.is_dead():
        print(f"{player.name}'s turn:")
        player_turn = True

        while player_turn:
            action = input("What do you want to do? (attack/restore/stats/gear): ").lower()
            if action == "attack" or action == "a":
                damage = player.attack()
                if player.weapon and player.weapon.element or player.attack_spell and player.attack_spell.element:
                    attack_element = player.weapon.element if player.weapon else player.attack_spell.element
                    if monster.element and attack_element in elements[monster.element]['weak_against']:
                        damage *= 1.5
                    elif monster.element and attack_element in elements[monster.element]['strong_against']:
                        damage *= 0.5
                monster.health -= damage
                print(f"{player.name} attacks {monster.name} for {damage:.2f} damage!")

                if monster.is_dead():
                    player.gain_exp(monster.exp)
                    break
                player_turn = False
            elif action == "stats" or action == "s":
                player.see_stats()
            elif action == "gear" or action == "g":
                player.see_gear()
            elif action == "restore" or action == "r":
                player.restore_health()
                player_turn = False
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid action.")

        if monster.is_dead():
            break

        print(f"{monster.name}'s turn:")
        m_damage = monster.attack_m()
        player.health -= m_damage
        print(f"{monster.name} attacks {player.name} for {m_damage:.2f} damage!")

        if player.is_dead():
            break

cure = restore_spell("cure", 50, 10)
fireball = attack_spell("fireball", 30, 15, "fire")
thunder = attack_spell("thunder", 25, 12, "electric")

player_weapon = weapon("Sword", 10, "normal")
player = Person(name="Hero", weapon=player_weapon, attack_spell=fireball, restore_spell=cure)

monster = Monster(name="Goblin", element="fire", max_health=250, health=250, max_mp=20, mp=20, magic=10, attack_spells=None)
monster.weapon = weapon("Claws", 5, "fire")

battle(player, monster)


I am trying to make something like a rpg game in python for understanding classes well. out of nowhere is_dead function start to cause this error('<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'). How can i improve my code and solve the issue
can you guys please help, i am new to python.
How can i solve this issue

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error as well as the sample input.  One thing I did notice, if attack_type == "magic" or "m": doesn't do what you think it does.

Your child classes that inherit from the Person class (Barbarian, Wizard, Monster) are problematic, specifically in their init methods. When you call the super's constructor, you are passing in arguments (like max_health, health, etc) as positional arguments, but you expect them to behave like keyword arguments. This has the result of armor equal to max_health, weapon becomes health, etc. You end up passing a string as a positional argument for the actual health or max_health, which will eventually break in is_dead when you try to compare a string with an integer.

In short, your Person class' __init__ expects many positional arguments, but you aren't giving it enough args/in the right order in your subclasses. For example, max_health is the 8th positional argument of your Person's __init__, so you need to pass arguments for all the other first 7 positional arguments before you pass max_health. Just because the name of the variable that you pass in happens to match the name of a parameter does not mean that Python will automatically know which parameter you intended to assign to.

The error message says '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. This means you used the <= operator trying to compare a string and an integer. Your function is_dead() has only one line, return self.health <= 0. We know that 0 is an integer. Therefore, at some point you are assigning a string to a Person's health attribute.
As Paul M already mentioned, the issue is in the call to super() in your Monster class.
super().__init__(name, max_health, health, max_mp, mp, magic, magic_defe, element, attack_spells)

You are missing the keyword specifiers in the function call. It should look like this:
super().__init__(name, max_health=max_health, health=health, max_mp=max_mp, mp=mp, magic=magic, magic_defe=magic_defe)

Python doesn't check the names of the variables in the caller scope and match them to the function signature, you have to provide the names. By omitting these, the parent class constructor is receiving the arguments in order. Meaning when Monster is initialized it assigns armor=max_health, weapon=health, attack_spell=max_mp, etc.
Also you are passing element and attack_spells to super()--but a Person does not have those attributes.
Same issue exists for other subclasses of Person.

Another thing--for your elements dict, I would strongly recommend using strong_against: [] rather than strong_against: ["None"]

Look at this line of code:
super().__init__(name, max_health, health, max_mp, mp, magic, magic_defe, element, attack_spells)

And this:
def __init__(self, name, armor=None, weapon=None, attack_spell=None, restore_spell=None, debuff=None, buff=None,
             max_health=100, health=None, max_mp=48, mp=None, strength=18, defe=12, dex=10, magic=20, magic_defe=12,
             luck=16, evasion=2, exp=0, lvl=1, skill_points=0, attack_accuracy=100, max_lvl=100, base_d=0,
             base_d_m=0):

In the Person's init function, health is the ninth parameter (not including self). However, when you are passing the value in, it is the third parameter. The same thing goes with max_health; it actually gets the element's value. Therefore, your values get mixed up and results in health being a string. Make sure you pass the values in the same order or use keyword arguments. I would recommend using keyword arguments to make it less confusing.
        super().__init__(name=name, max_health=max_health, health=health, max_mp=max_mp, mp=mp, magic=magic,
                         magic_defe=magic_defe)

There are more things to point out. All class names should be in PascalCase. For example: class armor should be class Armor. Also attack_type == 'magic' or 'm' is a bug. Since 'm' is not an empty string, it will evaluate to True making the whole statement true no matter what. Change that to attack_type == 'magic' or attack_type == 'm'. This also applies to attack_type == 'physical' or 'p'.

another syntax for checking attack_type, which I like to use for CLI kinda stuff: attack_type in ('magic', 'm')
